# Website Login with AJAX / PHP/ SQL Server Output GUID and store into Cookie or Session?

Tags: sql-server, ajax, cookies, web

I am new to ajax php and such so bear with me...

I am attempting to setup a internal website where users can login and upon login the user authenticates with a GUID that is generated on the SQL Server table side using a stored procedure with `NEWID()` and is returned from an AJAX to PHP call. This GUID would then be stored into a cookie perhaps?

I am attempting to use this GUID as Authentication for Web Sessions and User Rights based on a `User` access table in SQL Server. Apologies if this is a bit confusing...

Thanks Guys,

Below is the code from the AJAX Call:

```
// Distribute the variables to the div boxes
function loginpost() {
        var username = $('#Loginputusername').val();
        var password = $('#Loginputpassword').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            url: '../PHP/LoginSQL.php',
            data: {
                username: username, 
                password: password
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            success: function(result) {
// DIVS ON HTML THAT UPDATED THAT I AM TRYING TO PUT INTO A CLIENT SIDE COOKIE
                $('#one').html(result.session_id); 
                $('#two').html(result.status_id);
            }
        });
}
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php  
$databaseName = "WEB_DB" ;
$serverName = "50.50.50.50";   
$uid = "user";     
$pwd = "pass";     
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$IP_ADDRESS = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd ,                              
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);   

/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName , $connectionInfo); 


$tsql = "DECLARE 
@vsession_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
@vstatus_id varchar(MAX)

EXEC LOGIN_POST '$IP_ADDRESS', '$username',  @vSESSION_ID OUTPUT , @vSTATUS_ID OUTPUT
SELECT @vSESSION_ID AS session_id, @vSTATUS_ID AS status_id";

/* Execute the query. */    
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  

//Working Query
/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.    BR=."\n" */

while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_ARRAY($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
{ 
    echo json_encode($row);
}}  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);    

?>
```

This is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[LOGIN_POST]
    (@vIP VARCHAR(45) ,
     @vUSERNAME VARCHAR(25) ,
     @vSESSION_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER OUTPUT,
     @vSTATUS VARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT)
AS
    IF @vUSERNAME NOT IN (SELECT USERNAME 
                          FROM WEB_SESSION 
                          WHERE USERNAME = @vUSERNAME)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @vSESSION_ID = NEWID(), @vSTATUS ='Login Successful'
        SELECT @vSESSION_ID AS session_id, @vSTATUS AS status_id

        INSERT INTO WEB_SESSION (SESSION_ID, IP_ADDRESS, USERNAME, SESSION_START, LAST_ACTIVITY)
        VALUES(@vSESSION_ID, @vIP, @vUSERNAME, GETDATE(), GETDATE())
    END
ELSE
    IF @vUSERNAME IN (SELECT USERNAME 
                      FROM WEB_SESSION 
                      WHERE USERNAME = @vUSERNAME)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @VSTATUS = 'Login Failed ' + @vUSERNAME + ' is already logged in at ' + (SELECT IP_ADDRESS FROM WEB_SESSION WHERE USERNAME = @vUSERNAME)

        SELECT  
            CASE WHEN @vSESSION_ID IS NULL THEN ''
            END as session_id, 
            @vSTATUS AS status_id 
    END
```

SQL Server table that would store web sessions:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WEB_SESSION]
(
    [SESSION_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [IP_ADDRESS] [varchar](45) NOT NULL,
    [USERNAME] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [SESSION_START] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LAST_ACTIVITY] [datetime] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([USERNAME] ASC)
            WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
                  IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
                  ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```